# Google Drive API invalid_grant after removing access

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I have been writing a desktop application that uses the Google Drive API v2. I have the following code:

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
(
    new ClientSecrets { ClientId = ClientID, ClientSecret = ClientSecret },
    new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }, "user", CancellationToken.None
)
.Result;

this.Service = new DriveService( new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "My Test App",
} );

var request = this.Service.Files.List();
request.Q = "title = 'foo' and trashed = false";
var result = request.Execute();
```

The first time I ran this code it opened a browser and asked me to grant permissions to the App, which I did. Everything worked successfully until I realized I was using the wrong Google account. At that point I logged into the wrong Google account and revoked access to my App. Now, whenever I run the same code it throws an exception:

> Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""

When I examine the service and request objects, it looks like the oauth_token isn't getting created any more.

[image]

I know what I did to mess things up, but I can't figure out how to correct it so I can use a different Google account for testing. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored credentials are persisted using [StorageDataStore](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.WP/Apis/Util/Store/StorageDataStore.cs). You can either call the `DeleteAsync()` method or manually find and delete the file.

Comment: StorageDataStore isn't recognized. I have FileDataStore, but it expects a folder as a parameter. Am I missing something? Is there any way to tell if the credentials have expired or been revoked before it throws an exception?

Comment: More information about how credentials are stored is available here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth